# Converting a Bitv to uint

Tags: rust

I'm trying to convert a Bitv to uint.

```
use std::collections::Bitv;
use std::num::Float;

fn main() {
    let mut bv = Bitv::with_capacity(3,false);
    bv.set(2,true); // Set bit 3
    let deci = Vec::from_fn(bv.len(),|i| if bv.get(i) { 
                                    (i as f32).exp2() 
                                    } else { 0f32 }).iter()
                                                    .fold(0u, |acc, &n| acc+n as uint);
    println!["{}",deci] // 4
}
```

That works. Though I wanna know if there is any library function that I'm unaware of or is there any other better way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some transformations of your code I made.

#### Don't use floats

*Rust 1.0*

```
let vec: Vec<_> = (0..bv.len()).map(|i| {
    if bv[i] {
        1 << i
    } else {
        0
    }}).collect();
let deci = vec.iter().fold(0, |acc, &n| acc + n);
```

*Original*

```
let vec = Vec::from_fn(bv.len(), |i| {
    if bv.get(i) {
        1u << i
    } else {
        0u
    }});
let deci = vec.iter().fold(0u, |acc, &n| acc + n);
```

#### Don't make an array, just use a tuple

*Rust 1.0*

```
let deci = bv.iter()
    .fold((0, 0), |(mut acc, nth), bit| {
        if bit { acc += 1 << nth };
        (acc, nth + 1)
    }).0;
```

*Original*

```
let deci = bv.iter()
    .fold((0u, 0u), |(mut acc, nth), bit| {
        if bit { acc += 1 << nth };
        (acc, nth + 1)
    }).0;
```

#### A bit more usage of iterators

*Rust 1.0*

```
let deci = bv.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter_map(|(nth, bit)| if bit { Some(1 << nth) } else { None })
    .fold(0, |acc, val| acc + val);
```

*Original*

```
let deci = bv.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter_map(|(nth, bit)| if bit { Some(1 << nth) } else { None })
    .fold(0u, |acc, val| acc + val);
```

Ideally, you could reorganize your code to make use of [to_bytes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/bitv/struct.Bitv.html#method.to_bytes), but the order of bits is different from your example.

Answer (score 2):

`Bitv` doesn't provide a way to return its value as a `uint`, because the `Bitv` might contain more bits than a `uint` does. BTW, the size of `uint` is architecture-dependant (32 bits on 32-bit systems, 64 bits on 64-bit systems), so you should prefer using `u32` or `u64` unless you really need a `uint`.

`Bitv` provides the [`to_bytes`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.Bitv.html#method.to_bytes) and [`to_bools`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.Bitv.html#method.to_bools) methods, which return a `Vec<u8>` and a `Vec<bool>`, respectively. A `Vec<u8>` is more compact than a `Vec<bool>`, so `to_bytes` should be preferred when the `Bitv` is known to be large (but if it's known to be large, why would you try converting it to a `uint`?).

We can also iterate on the bits directly by using [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.Bitv.html#method.iter).

```
use std::collections::Bitv;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let mut bv = Bitv::with_capacity(3, false);
    bv.set(2, true); // Set bit 3

    let deci = bv.iter().enumerate().fold(
        0u64,
        |accum, (bit_pos, bit)| {
            if bit {
                assert!(bit_pos < mem::size_of_val(&accum) * 8);
                accum + (1 << bit_pos)
            } else {
                accum
            }
        });

    println!("{}", deci); // 4
}
```

Comment: The assertion is a good idea if we don't know the length of the input `Bitv`, but couldn't we move it to the beginning and just check once, before we iterate?

Comment: I placed the `assert!` such that extra zero bits at the end wouldn't panic. I checked quickly and `Bitv` doesn't provide a method to get the index of the most-significant one bit... If you have a better solution, feel free to edit it in!